# Por que meu input radio está retornando "on"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho [este código](http://jsfiddle.net/yqLo0nms/):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[name='valor1']").on('blur',function(){
        $(".empresa1").text($(this).val());
        $(".valor1").val($(this).val());
    });
    $("[name='valor2']").on('blur',function(){    
            $(".empresa2").text($('[name="valor2"]').val());
            $(".valor2").val($('[name="valor2"]').val());
    });    
    $("[name='valor3']").on('blur',function(){    
            $(".empresa3").text($('[name="valor3"]').val());
            $(".valor3").val($('[name="valor3"]').val());
    });   
    $("[name='empresa1']").on('click',function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
    $("[name='empresa2']").on('click',function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="valor1" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="valor2" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="valor3" value=""/>

<BR/><BR/><BR/>
<label class="empresa1"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa1" class="valor1" val=""/>
<label class="empresa2"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa1" class="valor2" val=""/>
<label class="empresa3"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa1" class="valor3" val=""/>
<BR/>
<label class="empresa1"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa2" class="valor1" val=""/>
<label class="empresa2"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa2" class="valor2" val=""/>
<label class="empresa3"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa2" class="valor3" val=""/>
```

A ideia é preencher os 3 inputs, popular o value do input radio e escrever o texto digitado nos labels.

O problema: se eu não digitar nenhum valor e clicar em um dos radio buttons, é impresso o valor `"on"`.

Entrem no jsfiddle que fiz acima, apertem o radio button sem digitar nada e verifiquem o `alert` que irá aparecer, por que isso? Tem como deixar ele vazio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seus radios não têm o atributo `value`, você parece ter usado `val` no lugar. Quando os radios não têm valor, é postado esse valor `"on"`.

Você parece estar querendo construir algo assim:

```
<label class="empresa1"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa1" class="valor1"  value=""/>
<label class="empresa2"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa1" class="valor1"  value=""/>
<label class="empresa3"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa1" class="valor1"  value=""/>
<br/>
<label class="empresa1"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa2" class="valor1"  value=""/>
<label class="empresa2"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa2" class="valor1"  value=""/>
<label class="empresa3"></label><input type="radio" name="empresa2" class="valor1"  value=""/>
```

Comment: eu tenho um formulário que o usuário deve digitar os inputs texts informando uma empresa, a partir desse input text digitado, terei que popular nos radio buttons das próximas questões. esse metódo que fiz vai funcionar? lógico que há mais tratamentos (de obrigar a ele a digitar os input texts, etc).

Comment: Acho que sim. Voltei as classes do seu código. Colei no seu fiddle pra ver como funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/yqLo0nms/1/